# Why is the list annotated twice after the foldl in haskell?

Tags: haskell, bubble-sort, fold

I'm trying to understand haskell, I can't really be convinced about what this line of code does, can someone detail the line of code for me?

Why does the **foldl** need to loop through the **xs** list twice?

The code is for the bubble sort algorithm.

```
burbuja xs = foldl (\acc _ -> bsort acc) xs xs
```

Comment: it doesn't need to loop twice, `xs` is just the "base case".

Comment: the `\acc _ ->` however looks very strange, that seems to suggest it simply repeats `bsort` that many times as there are items in `xs`.

Comment: That is a very cute trick, and I'm surprised I've never seen it before.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't run twice over the list, the `foldl (\x -> f x) xs xs` is a bit of a "sneaky" way to actually say that it should repeat the function on a value that many times as there are items in `xs`.

Indeed, `foldl f ys (x:xs)` is equivalent to `foldl f (f ys x) xs`, so it is a mechanism to apply `f` to the accumulator that starts with `ys` and uses the first item of the list `x`. But here the item of the list is ignoed.

It will thus, for a list `xs` with *n* items, work as:

```
bsort (bsort ((… (bsort xs) …))
```

where it thus applies the `bsort` function again on the result of the previous `bsort` that many times as there are elements in the list.